# How to I list down the results of a function (python)

Tags: python

I want to list down the sums taken from numberA.

The function "add" prompts the user if he wants to add. If he selects yes, then it will go to the function "numberA". This part will loop.

I want to list down the list of the sums when the user selects "N"  in the function "add". And finally sum up all the sums taken once again.

I do not know how to store the values taken from "numberA"

```
def numberA():
    num1=int(input("Enter First Number"))
    num2=int(input("Enter Second Number"))
    total=num1+num2
    print("The total: ", total)

def add():
    userSelect = input("Do You Want to Add?"
            "\n(Y) Yes ; (N) No"
            "\n")
    while userSelect != "Y" and userSelect != "N":
        print("Error")
        add()
    if userSelect == "Y":
        numberA()
        add()
    else:
        print("Bye")

add()
list = [add()] #List of the Sums go here
for each in list:
    print(each)
```

Comment: return the value from the functions, don't print the value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = []

def numberA():
    num1=int(input("Enter First Number"))
    num2=int(input("Enter Second Number"))
    total.append(num1+num2)

def add():
    userSelect = input("Do You Want to Add?"
            "\n(Y) Yes ; (N) No"
            "\n")
    while userSelect != "Y" and userSelect != "N":
        print("Error")
        add()
    if userSelect == "Y":
        numberA()
        add()
    else:
        print("Bye")

add()
print("The total: ")
for each in total:
    print(each)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! One more thing... Is there a way get the sum of the numbers that got printed?

Comment: How do I list it this way:

Your totals are: 1, 2, 3 and 4. The sum of those totals are: 10.

The numbers are separates by commas and the last number is separated by "and".

Thank You

Comment: You mean ``total = ['1', '2', '3', 'and', '4']`` ?

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to show the square brackets or apostrophes.

Comment: So the result should be: ``1, 2, 3 and 4``?

Comment: Yes. 1, 2, 3 and 4

Answer (score 0):

This help

```
def add():
    ask = True
    res = []
    while ask :
        num1=int(input("Enter First Number : "))
        num2=int(input("Enter Second Number : "))
        total = num1+num2
        userSelect = input("Do You Want to Add?"
        "\n(Y) Yes ; (N) No"
        "\n")
        if userSelect not in ['Y', 'N']:
            print "Error"
        elif userSelect == 'Y':
            ask = True
        else :
            ask = False
        res.append(total)
    return res
print add()
```